# java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed when reusing second time

Tags: java

I want to reuse a network socket. I tried this:

```
    private final static String WHOIS_HOST = "whois.verisign-grs.com";
    private final static int WHOIS_PORT = 43;

    @Test
    void justAnExample() {

        try {

            Socket socket = new Socket(WHOIS_HOST, WHOIS_PORT);
            socket.setSoTimeout(5000);

            sendRequest(socket, "cnn.com");

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            sendRequest(socket, "youtube.com");

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            sendRequest(socket, "toyota.com");

            socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendRequest(Socket socket, String domain) throws IOException {

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write((domain + "\r\n").getBytes());

        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("Registry Expiry Date")) {
                    line = line.substring(line.indexOf(':') + 1).trim();
                    System.out.println("---> " + line);
                    break; // don't need to read any more input
                }
            }

            final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
            if(line != null){
                final LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(line, formatter);
                System.out.println("---> " + dt);
                System.out.println("---> Not available " + domain);

            } else {
                System.out.println("---> Available " + domain);
            }
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

When I run the code I get this exception:

```
---> 2026-09-21T04:00:00Z
---> 2026-09-21T04:00
---> Not available cnn.com
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:998)
```

Do you know how I can reuse the socket many times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WHOIS protocol does not allow multiple requests to be sent over the same connection. According to [RFC 812](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc812), the specification that defines the WHOIS protocol:

> Connect to the service host (SRI-NIC) 
> TCP: service port 43 decimal 
> NCP: ICP to socket 43 decimal, establishing two 8-bit    connections
>
> Send a single "command line", ending with <CRLF>.
>
> Receive information in response to the command line.  The    server
> closes its connections as soon as the output is    finished.

As the last line indicates, the socket will be closed by the server after it has written its response. This means that a new socket needs to be opened for each request:

```
@Test
void justAnExample() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    sendRequest("cnn.com");

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    sendRequest("youtube.com");

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    sendRequest("toyota.com");
}

private void sendRequest(String domain) throws IOException {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(WHOIS_HOST, WHOIS_PORT)) {
        socket.setSoTimeout(5000);

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write((domain + "\r\n").getBytes());

        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("Registry Expiry Date")) {
                    line = line.substring(line.indexOf(':') + 1).trim();
                    System.out.println("---> " + line);
                    break; // don't need to read any more input
                }
            }

            final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
            if(line != null){
                final LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(line, formatter);
                System.out.println("---> " + dt);
                System.out.println("---> Not available " + domain);

            } else {
                System.out.println("---> Available " + domain);
            }
        }

        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Note that in this example, the `Socket` is created using a try-with-resources statement, to ensure it is closed correctly even in the case of an exception. It is not necessary to also close the `OutputStream` obtained from `socket.getOutputStream()`. This is closed when the `Socket` is.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream()) for `Socket.getOutputStream()`

> Closing the returned `OutputStream` will close the associated socket.

You are closing the stream in `sendRequest`, so the `Socket` will be closed.

---

> *Do you know how I can reuse the socket many times?*

Basically, you have to NOT close the socket.  But if the protocol that you are using requires you to close the socket (as WHOIS apparently does ... per [@TimMoore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780211/139985)) then you *cannot* reuse the socket.  And in this case, even if you didn't close the stream yourself, the WHOIS service will close the TCP connection from the other end.